# What would be the best way to count a certain element on a page and close a certain one

Tags: javascript

What would be the best approach to counting a certain element on a page and closing the parent of said element.

For example i have multiple alerts on a page and each one has the same attribute of `data-action="alert-close"`.

I want to close only the one that is clicked on. I'm looking for ideas of how to do this within JavaScript you don't have to give the complete code on how to do this just some methods and ideas.

Comment: What does counting have to do with this? Just add an event listener to all the elements, and when the user clicks on an element you close its parent.

Comment: `this.parentElement` in the event listener will get the parent.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("data-action='alert-close'")` will get all the elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know it was quite a dumb question but im still learning. Ive tested them all and finally got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Click on div to remove**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-action="alert-close"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    var parent = $this.parents('li:first');
    parent.remove();

    setCounter(); // refresh counter
  });


  setCounter(); // set counter after page load
});

function setCounter() {
  var count = $('[data-action="alert-close"]').length;
  $('.counter').text(count);

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Div Counter = <span class="counter"></span></li>

  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert-close">Div 6</div>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```